# CSS: Why does the view appearance change for changing browser width for fixed dimensions?

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with styled divs as shown in the below code.

With changing browser width the blue and the green box appearance is changing, though the dimensions of the boxes have fixed values, why is this happening and how can I ensure that the blue and green boxes take up the same space irrespective of the browser width ?

**Screen 1 (width 1040px)**
[image]

**Screen 2 (width 342px)**
[image]

**Html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example Position: fixed</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="timerContainer"></div>
      <div class="roomContainer">
        <div class="remoteParticipantContainer"></div>
        <div class="localParticipantContainer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the **Styles**

```
.container {
  position: static;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.timerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.roomContainer {
  position: absolute;
  background: darkGray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.remoteParticipantContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.localParticipantContainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: blue;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this meta tag inside `head` tag.
For `responsive` design, you need to define `viewport` meta.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no' />
```